# How to select from two SQL tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use foreign keys to link my SQL tables then call data with select statements.. My tables are

```
team table
team_id 
name

match table
match_id
team1_id
team2_id
round
```

I would like to select from the match table the match_id, where team1's name is "alpha" team2's name is "bravo" and round is 1. Think i need a JOIN, but a bit stuck on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

select m.* 
from team  t inner join on match m on t.team_id = m.team1_id and t.team2_id 
where t.name in ('alpha','bravo') and m.round = 1
```

Comment: ok thanks, i got this working with a few changes, and i also changed my table called match :)

Comment: @JS60:- You are welcome! Glad that I could make a helping hand. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT mt.*, tbl1.name as team1_name,tbl2.name as team2_name  from match_table as mt 
JOIN teamtable as tbl1 ON mt.team_id=tbl1.team1_id 
JOIN teamtable as tbl2 ON mt.team_id=tbl2.team12_id
WHERE mt.team1_id='alpha' AND mt.team2_id='bravo' AND mt.round=1;
```

Its not tested. Test it.